# Vb.Net The Difference Between SQlConnection Strings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hello guys i have simple Question about what is the difference between these SQlConnection Strings

1.

```
Dim Con As New SqlConnection("Server = Z\SQL; Database = Project; id = zzz; pwd = zzz integrated Security = true")
```

2. 

```
Dim Con As New SqlConnection("Driver = {SQL SERVER}; Server = Z\SQL; Database = Project; id = zzz; pwd = zzz integrated Security = true")
```

3. 

```
    Dim Con As New SqlConnection("@Server = Z\SQL; Database = Project; id = zzz; pwd = zzz integrated Security = true")
```

Also Which is the most optimal procedure?

Thanks before

Comment: 1 and 3 are the same string which would more than likely lead to pooling the two connections to one connection, wheras, the second seems to specify a specific ODBC driver to use while connecting.

Comment: OP: Please make some effort to provide valid connection strings (i.e. compatible with `SqlConnection`).

Comment: Hi @DiplomacyNotWar can you please give me example for valid connection strings? I can’t provide because i’m still learning & don’t really understand where’s the mistake. Thanks before

Comment: Valid ones would be ones that aren't rejected by SqlConnection when I try to test them. If you're not sure, use SqlConnectionStringBuilder to build your connection string.

Comment: i've found the answer bro, the example 1 and 3 are same, also you don't use Integrated security = true if you want to use uid & pwd because it will check for Windows Aunthetication, thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 1 and 2 Code are the same, and if you don't want to access your SQL by Windows Aunthetication then set the Integrated Security to False and then add UID (Sql Login Id) & PWD (Password) into the string.

thanks anyone.